# GAMS compile to GDX drops column with all zero values

Tags: gams-math

NOTE: Update (but not solved) Below

In my use case for GAMS I wish to define a collection of static variables in a .gdx file rather than in the main model.gms script. This is not an issue unless I define a column that contains only zero (0) values. When defining a table ("data") like this and choosing "Run with GDX Creation in GAMS studio. I get a .gdx file with a missing column.

```
Set indexA  /ch1*ch5/;

Table data(indexA, *) 

        A_min    A_max   B_min    B_max    
ch1     1        10      0        7
ch2     2        10      0        6
ch3     3        10      0        5
ch4     4        10      0        4
ch5     5        10      0        3;
```

Copy and pasted .gdx contents:

```
IndexA *        Value
ch1    A_min    1
ch1    A_max    10
ch1    B_max    7
ch2    A_min    2
ch2    A_max    10
ch2    B_max    6
ch3    A_min    3
ch3    A_max    10
ch3    B_max    5
ch4    A_min    4
ch4    A_max    10
ch4    B_max    4
ch5    A_min    5
ch5    A_max    10
ch5    B_max    3
```

Column 'B_min' is nowhere to be seen. When trying to load this .gdx back into my script it gives me an error where I try to access 'B_min' and says "Label is unknown". If I change the value to be non zero, it is not a problem, but I need it to be zero! I have tried using 0.0 vs 0. No change. Why can't I define something to be zero and have it save in my .gdx?

Edit / Update:
I created an ugly work around for this. I set all of my "B_min values to -1 in gams, created my .gdx file with the column, but the wrong values. Loaded the .gdx file into python using the GAMS API, iterated over each entry in 'data' to change the -1 values to 0 and saved it. This new .gdx file now works in my test model. I would still really like to get this zero thing solved for others on my team who are not going to use this work around with the python API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency GAMS does not store default values, thus no zeros in parameters. What you probably can do is setting [$onEps](https://www.gams.com/33/docs/UG_DollarControlOptions.html#DOLLARonoffeps). This will transform your zeros into `eps`, which is numerically still zero but makes it into the GDX file.